# Formula to calculate latest date from different orders in a report

Tags: formula, reporting

Hey guys :) so I'm stuck here...

I got a report in salesforce containing an 'Issue Date' field, and it would help me a lot if I had the latest date from different orders...

I tried to create a field with a MAX formula but I didn't manage to reach what I really need.

Here's a pic of what I'm thinking (there's more than 3 dates btw):

[image]

Is it possible to solve this editing the report?

Comment: Formula can only deal with individual record and its parents. It cannot access other records to calculate something. Achieving what you looking for is going to be expensive and/or inaccurate as you will have to do the work yourself in batch jobs and process all records to calculate latest date.

Comment: Easy: Sort orders by date within your Brand group, that can be part of the report definition so users don't need to do it. Harder: summary-level formula (SLF) in a report. SLFs don't work on dates so you'll need to convert date to string or number, SLF it, then convert back to date.